# Eliminar objetos de un JSON desde JS

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject

Hice una función eliminar que se encarga de borrar objetos de un JSON dependiendo del titulo que le pases por consola, La función eliminar trabaja correctamente elimina la tarea con el titulo que le pido, pero cuando le paso un titulo incorrecto me elimina siempre la ultima tarea del JSON, y no quiero que pase eso, sino que en caso de que el titulo se incorrecto salga un mensaje "No se encontró la tarea" ¿como lo puedo arreglar?

> este es la funcion eliminar del JS

```
eliminarTareaPorNombre: function(titulo) {
   let listadoArrayDeTareas = this.leerJSON();
   let tareaEliminada = listadoArrayDeTareas.splice(listadoArrayDeTareas.findIndex(tarea => 
   tarea.titulo.toLowerCase() === titulo.toLowerCase()), 1);
   this.escribirJSON(listadoArrayDeTareas);
   return tareaEliminada
 },
 };
```

> Este es el JSON

```
[
{
"titulo": "chau",
"estado": "pendiente"
},
{
"titulo": "Buenos Dias",
"estado": "pendiente"
}
]
```

> Este es el case de mi Switch que devuelve los mensajes dependiendo de la situación(esta en otro JS)

```
case 'eliminar' :
let eliminadas = archivoTareas.eliminarTareaPorNombre(accion2);
eliminadas.forEach(tarea => {
if(tarea.titulo == accion2){
console.log();
console.log('tareas eliminadas');
console.log('------------------');
console.log(tarea.titulo)
console.log();
}else{
console.log('No se encontro esa tarea')
}
 });
break;
}
```

> Una aclaración que quiero hacer es que cuando pongo un titulo incorrecto el case funciona perfectamente, tira por la consola el mensaje "No se encontró la tarea" el problema esta en el JS porque aunque le pase el titulo incorrecto si borra la tarea del JSON

espero haberme dado entender, agradecería mucho una respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo lo que tienes es un objeto con un método para eliminar los items que hay dentro del mismo objeto. me parece que tu manera está bien ejecutada, el problema es que `findIndex()` si no encuentra ningún resultado siempre retornará -1 por lo que para tu forma de aplicarlo, `splice(-1)` siempre eliminará tu ultimo item.

**Por lo que te propongo la siguiente lógica**:

```js
let parent = {
  tasks: [
    {
      "titulo": "chau",
      "estado": "pendiente"
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Buenos Dias",
      "estado": "pendiente"
    }
  ],
  deleteTasks(dtask) {
    let re = dtask ? new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)(' + dtask + ')(?:$|\\W)', 'ig') : null
    let tasks = this.tasks;
    let update = re ? tasks.filter(task => !re.test(task.titulo)) : tasks;
    let del = re ? tasks.filter(task => re.test(task.titulo)) : [];
    this.tasks = update;
    return del;
  }
}

console.log("TASKS ORIGINAL: ",parent.tasks)
console.log("TASKS ELIMINADAS: ", parent.deleteTasks("chau"))
console.log("TASKS MODIFICADO: ", parent.tasks)
```

Como ves, utilizo `filter()` para filtrar si hay un match con la expresión regular que en este caso es el parámetro con insensibilidad de mayúsculas. Utilicé dos filtros, uno para actualizar el array y otro para retornar la función con los valores eliminados, pero con un poco de ingenio podrías acortar bastante la función.

Como adicional te la dejo en forma de callback para que veas que puedes hacer una especie de state tracker con la función:

```js
let parent = {
  tasks: [
    {
      "titulo": "chau",
      "estado": "pendiente"
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Buenos Dias",
      "estado": "pendiente"
    }
  ],
  deleteTasks(dtask, cb) {
    let re = dtask ? new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)(' + dtask + ')(?:$|\\W)', 'ig') : null
    let tasks = this.tasks;
    const o = tasks;
    let update = re ? tasks.filter(task => !re.test(task.titulo)) : tasks;
    let del = re ? tasks.filter(task => re.test(task.titulo)) : [];
    this.tasks = update;
    return cb(o,del,update);
  }
}

parent.deleteTasks("buenos dias", (prev, del, next) => {
  console.log("TASKS ORIGINAL: ",prev)
  console.log("TASKS ELIMINADAS: ", del)
  console.log("TASKS MODIFICADO: ", next)
})
```

> **EDIT:** Modifiqué el RegExp para que solo funcione si es exacto el titulo.

- **Antes**: `let re = dtask ? new RegExp(dtask), 'i') : null`
- **Después**: `let re = dtask ? new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)(' + dtask + ')(?:$|\\W)', 'ig') : null`

Ahora solo es true si el string es exactamente igual al parámetro, pero aun así indiferentemente de si es minúscula o mayúscula.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.